# Performance Issue with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, spring, performance, hibernate

The environment currently I have is hibernate with MSS and spring boot.I have slow performance on select queries statements with large tables using MSS ,however using MYSQL working fine.The configuration is below

```
> datasource:
>     driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver              
>     url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
>     username: test
>     password: test
```

Appreciated

Comment: We'd need to see what queries you're running and how the tables are set up in each database before we could even take a guess.

Comment: There is not much information to go on. One thing you can try is to turn of logging sql statments and check if they are what you are expecting. Other then that its probably problem with the MSS setup.

Comment: Can you show some code? Maybe your code is not well optimised.

Comment: Thnx guys ,what could be the problem with MSS even it's working fine on mysql?

Comment: Maybe there is no problem.  Maybe - just maybe - MySQL is just better than MSS at this point in time.  :)